# Using awk to extract gcc version

Tags: gcc, awk, version

I would like to get the gcc version with the awk command, but the returned string is empty.

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 11.1.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
$ gcc --version | head -1 | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if(match($i,/^[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]$/))  {print $i; exit 0}}}'
$
```

Don't know why it fails. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking one-digit numbers only.

Just allow multiple digits and it must work, something like this:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if(match($i,/^[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*$/))  {print $i; exit 0}}}'
```

gcc also has a short version option:

> -dumpversion

So you don't need awk for that :)

Answer (score 2):

```
gcc -dumpfullversion
```

Output:

```
9.3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
gcc --version |  awk '{ print $NF;exit }'
```

output (on my system):

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ gcc --version |  awk '{ print $NF;exit }'
9.3.0
$
```

OR:

```
gcc -dumpspecs | grep -A1 version | tail -1
```